# Should class member instances and local method variables be dynamically allocated

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and am still trying to understand static vs dynamic memory and when to use each one... I was working on a program and wrote this:

```cpp
class WadFile
{
private:
    std::vector<Lump*> lumps;
public:
    std::vector<char> data;
    int num_lumps;
    int pos;
    char type[5];
    Lump *GetLumpName(const char *name);
    WadFile(std::ifstream *stream);
    ~WadFile();
};
```

However, the number of `WadFile`s is indeterminate, the user can open as many as he wants at a time; I am presuming that `lumps` should instead be a pointer to a new std::vector that is created in the constructor, and deleted in the destructor... am I correct? While analyzing this further I realized something here:

```cpp
void WadReader::Open(const char *wadname)
{
    std::ifstream stream(
        wadname,
        std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
    
    file = new WadFile(&stream);
};
```

Assuming one `WadReader` per `WadFile`, what becomes of the `std::ifstream`? There can be many instances with the method, containing an ifstream; should this also be dynamically allocated?

Comment: Avoid dynamic allocation unless you have a specific reason to use it. Even if you need it, never call `new`/`delete` manually, use containers and smart pointers (only use `new`/`delete` when writing custom containers and smart pointers). Avoid writing destructors, copy/move constructors and assignments, most of the time you don't need them.

Comment: *However, the number of WadFiles is indeterminate* -- That translates to `std::vector<WadFile>`, which your code snippet doesn't show. -- *I am presuming that lumps should instead be a pointer to a new std::vector* -- We have no idea what `Lump` is, so we cannot presume anything.

Comment: Raw pointers and `new`/`delete` are advanced topics that are rarely correct for new C++ programmers.

Comment: Presumably the context is the WAD file format https://doomwiki.org/wiki/WAD "A WAD file consists of a header, a directory, and the data lumps that make up the resources stored within the file."

Answer (score 2):

> am presuming that lumps should instead be a pointer to a new std::vector that is created in the constructor, and deleted in the destructor... am I correct?

No, you almost never want a pointer to standard container. `std::vector` manages internal array itself that will grow as needed. Also, most likely `lumps` should be `std::vector<Lump>`, no pointers involved (unless `Lump` is a class that can be inherited from, then it should be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Lump>>`).

> Assuming one WadReader per WadFile, what becomes of the std::ifstream? There can be many instances with the method, containing an ifstream; should this also be dynamically allocated?

As it is now, `stream` is dead by the end of `Open` function, so unless `WadFile` constructor does a very peculiar thing of moving from dereferenced pointer, every `WadFile` created in this function has a dangling pointer.

I'd expect `WadFile` to also accept a filename as input and leave stream handling as internal detail (but then, there's little need for `WadReader`). Or some more detailed design such that `WadReader` keeps the stream, but `WadFile` requires a reference to one for each operation. Hard to say with this little code.

Comment: So every time `Lump lump; lumps.push_back(lump);` is run, a new lump is dynamically created with a managed life cycle? I understand the stack does not grow, so that's my concern. `lumps` is also indeterminate

Comment: @K.RussellSmith `std::vector` doesn't store its content on the stack. It internally has an array allocated on the heap that stores all the objects. `Lump lump; lumps.push_back(lump);` makes the vector add a copy of `lump` at the end of said array, reallocating it as needed.